# How to create file in Prestashop Module folder at time of installation

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am new in Prestashop module development. I am trying to create a txt file at the time of module installation, but neither it create file nor it showing error.

here is my code

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
  exit;

class MyModule extends Module
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->name = 'mymodule';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.0.0';
    $this->author = 'Firstname Lastname';
    $this->need_instance = 0;
    $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_); 
    $this->bootstrap = true;

    parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('My module');
    $this->description = $this->l('Description of my module.');

    $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l('Are you sure you want to uninstall?');

    if (!Configuration::get('MYMODULE_NAME'))      
      $this->warning = $this->l('No name provided');
  }

    public function install()
    {
      if (!parent::install())
        return false;

        // create file at time of installation
        $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        $txt = "hello world\n";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt);
        fclose($myfile);

        return true;
    }

    public function uninstall()
    {
      if (!parent::uninstall())
        return false;

      // delete created file
      delete("newfile.txt");
      return true;
    }

}
```

Please tell me how to debug at module development in Prestashop.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Admin (back office) is used through the index.php in the admin folder, if you don't specify the folder where to create the file, it will be created there (in the admin folder).
To create the file in your module folder use something like:

```
$file = _PS_MODULE_DIR_ . $this->name .'/newfile.txt';
```